# Row transferred to next page get Calculated in the current page (Or previous page from where it was prevented to be printed)

Tags: jasper-reports

How can I understand that a special row in the *Detail* section of a report (with Slpit Type = prevent) has transferred to the next page to prevent split?

I need to do this because I have a report with a numeric column(suppose its name is quantity) per row which I want to show summation of that column for all records in every page, the desired value will calculate from summation of quantity columns in current page and all previous pages(suppose its name is qSum). If i allow splitting for Detail band rows, there is no problem, but when I prevent splitting, the quantity column value of splitted row will add to calculated summation (qSum) of current page, but the row itself will shown in the next page!

any idea ?

In order words how can I force the summation to be only for the row appearing on that page. (excluding the transferred row)

My column summation is the column footer.

Below is partial part of my report:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="generalLedger01" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="806" leftMargin="18" rightMargin="18" topMargin="4" bottomMargin="14" isFloatColumnFooter="true">
    <parameter name="zero" class="java.math.BigDecimal" isForPrompting="false">
        <property name="&quot;&quot;" value="0"/>
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new BigDecimal(0)]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="firstPageNumber" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="budgetAllocation" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="&quot;&quot;" value="0"/>
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new BigDecimal(0)]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="lastPageNumber" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="paramYear" class="java.lang.Long">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="paramAccCode" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
     voucher.`rec_no` AS voucher_rec_no,
     voucher.`acc_code` AS voucher_acc_code,
     voucher.`acc_name` AS voucher_acc_name,
     voucher.`pers_code` AS voucher_pers_code,
     voucher.`mult_single` AS voucher_mult_single,
     voucher.`debit_credit` AS voucher_debit_credit,
     voucher.`corr_ac_code` AS voucher_corr_ac_code,
     voucher.`voucher_no` AS voucher_voucher_no,
     voucher.`conv_rate` AS voucher_conv_rate,
     voucher.`entry_amount` AS voucher_entry_amount,
     voucher.`dollar_taka` AS voucher_dollar_taka,
     voucher.`details_1` AS voucher_details_1,
     voucher.`details_2` AS voucher_details_2,
     voucher.`details_3` AS voucher_details_3,
     voucher.`gj_1` AS voucher_gj_1,
     voucher.`gj_2` AS voucher_gj_2,
     voucher.`gj_3` AS voucher_gj_3,
     voucher.`amount` AS voucher_amount,
     voucher.`voucher_tag` AS voucher_voucher_tag,
     voucher.`voucher_date` AS voucher_voucher_date,
     voucher.`voucher_day` AS voucher_voucher_day,
     voucher.`voucher_month` AS voucher_voucher_month,
     voucher.`voucher_year` AS voucher_voucher_year,
     voucher.`voucher_quater` AS voucher_voucher_quater,
     code.code_name as codeName,
     subcode.sub_code_name as subCodeName
FROM
     `voucher` voucher, `code` code,`sub_code` subcode

where (  ((code.code=$P{paramAccCode})or(subcode.sub_code=$P{paramAccCode}))
         and
            voucher.`voucher_year`=$P{paramYear}
       and
            ( voucher.`acc_code`=$P{paramAccCode}
              or
             voucher.`corr_ac_code`=$P{paramAccCode}
            )
      )


GROUP BY

     voucher.`voucher_quater`,
     voucher.`voucher_month` ,
     voucher.`voucher_day` ,
     voucher.`rec_no`;]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="voucher_rec_no" class="java.math.BigInteger"/>
    <field name="voucher_acc_code" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="voucher_acc_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="voucher_pers_code" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="voucher_mult_single" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="voucher_debit_credit" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="voucher_corr_ac_code" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="voucher_voucher_no" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="voucher_conv_rate" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="voucher_entry_amount" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="voucher_dollar_taka" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="voucher_details_1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="voucher_details_2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="voucher_details_3" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="voucher_gj_1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="voucher_gj_2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="voucher_gj_3" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="voucher_amount" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="voucher_voucher_tag" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="voucher_voucher_date" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="voucher_voucher_day" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <field name="voucher_voucher_month" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <field name="voucher_voucher_year" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <field name="voucher_voucher_quater" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <field name="codeName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="subCodeName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="balance" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[((($F{voucher_debit_credit}.equals("A"))&&(!(($F{voucher_corr_ac_code}).equals($P{paramAccCode}))))?($V{balance}.add($F{voucher_amount})):($V{balance}.subtract($F{voucher_amount})))]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new BigDecimal(0)]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="balance_tk" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[((($F{voucher_debit_credit}.equals("A"))&&(!(($F{voucher_corr_ac_code}).equals($P{paramAccCode}))))?($V{balance_tk}.add($F{voucher_entry_amount})):($V{balance_tk}.subtract($F{voucher_entry_amount})))]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new BigDecimal(0)]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="balance_credit" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Column" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{voucher_amount}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="balance_debit" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Column" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{voucher_amount}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="monthTotalDebit" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[((($F{voucher_debit_credit}.equals("A"))&&(!(($F{voucher_corr_ac_code}).equals($P{paramAccCode}))))?$F{voucher_amount}:$P{zero})]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new BigDecimal(0)]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="pageTotalCredit" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Page" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[(($F{voucher_debit_credit}.equals("B")||(($F{voucher_corr_ac_code}).equals($P{paramAccCode})))?$F{voucher_amount}:$P{zero})]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="pageTotalCredit_tk" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Page" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[(($F{voucher_debit_credit}.equals("B")||(($F{voucher_corr_ac_code}).equals($P{paramAccCode})))?$F{voucher_entry_amount}:(($F{voucher_debit_credit}.equals("B")||(($F{voucher_corr_ac_code}).equals($P{paramAccCode})))?$F{voucher_entry_amount}:$P{zero}))]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="monthTotalCredit" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[(($F{voucher_debit_credit}.equals("B")||(($F{voucher_corr_ac_code}).equals($P{paramAccCode})))?$F{voucher_amount}:$P{zero})]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="pageTotalDebit_tk" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Page" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[((($F{voucher_debit_credit}.equals("A"))&&(!(($F{voucher_corr_ac_code}).equals($P{paramAccCode}))))?$F{voucher_entry_amount}:$P{zero})]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="pageTotalDebit" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Page" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[((($F{voucher_debit_credit}.equals("A"))&&(!(($F{voucher_corr_ac_code}).equals($P{paramAccCode}))))?$F{voucher_amount}:$P{zero})]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="monthTotalCredit_tk" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[(($F{voucher_debit_credit}.equals("B")||(($F{voucher_corr_ac_code}).equals($P{paramAccCode})))?$F{voucher_entry_amount}:(($F{voucher_debit_credit}.equals("B")||(($F{voucher_corr_ac_code}).equals($P{paramAccCode})))?$F{voucher_entry_amount}:$P{zero}))]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="monthTotalDebit_tk" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[((($F{voucher_debit_credit}.equals("A"))&&(!(($F{voucher_corr_ac_code}).equals($P{paramAccCode}))))?$F{voucher_entry_amount}:$P{zero})]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new BigDecimal(0)]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="voucher_voucher_quater">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{voucher_voucher_quater}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="16">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="41" y="0" width="56" height="16"/>
                    <box>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                        <font fontName="Courier New" size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[""]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="96" y="0" width="46" height="16"/>
                    <box leftPadding="2"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Courier New" size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[""]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement x="142" y="0" width="198" height="16"/>
                    <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="4">
                        <leftPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font fontName="Courier New" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["SUB TOTAL:"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="#,##0.00">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="340" y="0" width="74" height="16"/>
                    <box rightPadding="2"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font fontName="Courier New" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{monthTotalDebit_tk}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="#,##0.00">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="414" y="0" width="74" height="16"/>
                    <box rightPadding="2">
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font fontName="Courier New" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{monthTotalCredit_tk}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="#,##0.00">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="488" y="0" width="74" height="16"/>
                    <box leftPadding="0" rightPadding="2">
                        <rightPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font fontName="Courier New" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{balance_tk}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <group name="voucher_voucher_month">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{voucher_voucher_month}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="voucher_voucher_day">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{voucher_voucher_day}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="voucher_voucher_tag">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{voucher_voucher_tag}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="119" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="414" y="104" width="74" height="15"/>
                <box topPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue()==1?"" :$V{monthTotalCredit_tk})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="142" y="105" width="198" height="14"/>
                <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="2">
                    <leftPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue()==1?"" :"B/F")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="97" y="105" width="46" height="14"/>
                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[""]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="340" y="105" width="74" height="14"/>
                <box topPadding="2" rightPadding="2"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[(($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue()==1)?"":$V{monthTotalDebit_tk} )]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="41" y="104" width="56" height="15"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[""]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="488" y="105" width="74" height="14"/>
                <box topPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <rightPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[(($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue()==1)?"":$V{balance_tk} )]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="149" y="57" width="43" height="11"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{paramAccCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="340" y="90" width="74" height="15"/>
                <box topPadding="3">
                    <topPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[DEBIT]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="414" y="90" width="74" height="15"/>
                <box topPadding="3">
                    <topPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[CREDIT]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="488" y="90" width="74" height="15"/>
                <box topPadding="3">
                    <topPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[BALANCE]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="97" y="90" width="45" height="15"/>
                <box topPadding="3">
                    <topPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Vr .No.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="142" y="90" width="198" height="15"/>
                <box topPadding="3">
                    <topPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[CHEQUE NO./EXPLANATION]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="719" y="0" width="66" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page : "+($V{PAGE_NUMBER}+$P{firstPageNumber})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="334" y="35" width="273" height="14"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["FOR THE FISCAL YEAR "+$F{voucher_voucher_year}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="¤ #,##0.00">
                <reportElement x="143" y="79" width="30" height="10"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" US$.   "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="41" y="90" width="55" height="15"/>
                <box topPadding="3">
                    <topPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[DATE]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="344" y="22" width="108" height="13"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="9" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[GENERAL LEDGER]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="340" y="75" width="222" height="15"/>
                <box topPadding="3">
                    <topPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[IN BANGLADESH TAKA]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="149" y="68" width="191" height="11"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{subCodeName}.isEmpty()?$F{codeName}:$F{subCodeName})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00">
                <reportElement x="174" y="79" width="166" height="10"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{budgetAllocation}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="39" y="57" width="110" height="11"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["ACCOUNT CODE                :"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="39" y="68" width="110" height="11"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["ACCOUNT NAME                :"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="39" y="79" width="110" height="11"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["BUDGET ALLOCATION       :"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="14" splitType="Prevent">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="#,##0.00">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="414" y="0" width="74" height="14" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <box rightPadding="2">
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[(($F{voucher_debit_credit}.equals("B")||(($F{voucher_corr_ac_code}).equals($P{paramAccCode})))?$F{voucher_entry_amount}:"")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="41" y="0" width="56" height="14" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{voucher_voucher_date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="#,##0.00">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="488" y="0" width="74" height="14" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <box leftPadding="0" rightPadding="2">
                    <rightPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{balance_tk}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="142" y="0" width="198" height="14" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <box leftPadding="3">
                    <leftPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{voucher_details_1}+$F{voucher_details_2}+$F{voucher_details_3}+"\n"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="#,##0.00">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="340" y="0" width="74" height="14" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <box rightPadding="2"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[((($F{voucher_debit_credit}.equals("A"))&&(!(($F{voucher_corr_ac_code}).equals($P{paramAccCode}))))?$F{voucher_entry_amount}:"")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="804" y="0" width="1" height="14" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <box rightPadding="2">
                    <rightPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[""]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="97" y="0" width="46" height="14" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <box leftPadding="3"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{voucher_voucher_no}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="14" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00">
                <reportElement x="488" y="0" width="74" height="13"/>
                <box topPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <topPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{balance_tk}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00">
                <reportElement x="414" y="0" width="74" height="13"/>
                <box topPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <topPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{monthTotalCredit_tk}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00">
                <reportElement x="340" y="0" width="74" height="13"/>
                <box topPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <topPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{monthTotalDebit_tk}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="42" y="0" width="298" height="13"/>
                <box topPadding="2">
                    <topPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Courier New" size="8" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[(($V{PAGE_NUMBER}+$P{firstPageNumber})==$P{lastPageNumber})?"GRAND TOTAL":"TOTAL C/F"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
    <lastPageFooter>
        <band/>
    </lastPageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Just get the solution to this miscalculation of forwarded rows by ireport. I sharing it in case someone get into a similar problem.

Comment: Whenever a row spread over two consecutives pages ireport becomes confused. Instead of using **split type= prevent** as option in the detail band , set it to **split type= Stretch**. Then create a dummy group (by primary key of the row) with group header and footer enabled that will act as a container for each row . Dummy group option are: reprint header=true, Min Height to start new= value of detail band height, Footer Position= normal, **Keep together= true**. Hope it helps...

Comment: Now if each is processed as group and will be forwarded to next page it cannot fit a the current one. This scenario is common with financial accounting report when you have credit , debit and has to calculate a running balance with carry forward and bring forward totals.